# How can you password protect your frontend while you start developing a page, and which is the safest web hosting service?

Tags: joomla-3.x, front-end, localhost

I'm quite a beginner in Joomla; only designed 1 website so far; but the whole setup / domain name + web hosting configuration and lock of the frontend was made in advance for me; so I'd really like to know how to do all of that in the safest and easiest way on a mac with the newest version of joomla. I work on a macbook pro, version 10.13.6. I really want to create a administrator (and locked frontend) page which I can access from any computer to work on; so I guess the solution via XAMPP is not an option..

Comment: This question risks being Too Broad and appears to be unresearched.  If you have made any strides yourself, you might be able to narrow down what you are asking of volunteers here.  Generally, we don't want to encourage long-ish multi-step tutorials here.  This community is most effectively used when you have a single, narrow issue to resolve.  Please edit your question.

Comment: To help you clarify your question more, are you wanting to create a new website, different to the one that was set up for you, or do you wish to have a copy of the website you already have that you can update to the latest version of Joomla? And what to you mean by 'lock of the frontend' and 'locked frontend'? Can you provide a link to your existing website?

Comment: You could simply put the website in offline mode which only those with permission can access after they login. You can set the permissions to super admin only of you wish

Answer (score 1):

So why not just set the page in the joomla configuration to „offline“ or did i missed something in your question? Its exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin called n3t coming soon which may help you with this. When enabled it will show a coming soon  page (which you can customise if you like) while letting you view the site. It uses your IP address to decide whether you can see the site or not.

https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/n3t-coming-soon/